# Manage http network request priority

Tags: javascript, html, http

When a webpage loads, it'll initiate network requests for all the images, videos, javascript files, css files, and other assets. The browser will only open sockets for up to six of these requests at a time, stalling the others in a queue based on the browser's priority. This priority appears to place javascript files, css files, and font files above images.

Is there a way to tell the browser to prioritize specified images above font files and other assets?

Comment: You could load the images above the other elements in the DOM... though this would require making use of inline styles and script to validate correctly.

Comment: It appears that even inline scripts are given priority over images above them in the DOM. The images will queue before the javascript files, but stall until the javascript files are loaded.

Comment: What is the *actual* problem -- why do you want some images loaded first? Maybe this is an XYProblem (http://xyproblem.info/) situation?